# Do we need to write Junit for ONOpen, OnMessage methods in websocket server end pont

Tags: java, for-loop, junit, websocket

I need help to write the Junit for my class, does it have any value to write Junit for this, If yes please help how to write with example.
    Thank you in advance.

```
my code is :

@ServerEndpoint(
    value="/mysocketServer", 
    encoders = { MessageEncoder.class }, 
    decoders = { MessageDecoder.class })
public class WebSocketService {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException, FTPWebSocketException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(ackResponse);       
    }


    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable t) {
        logger.error("OnError ocurred for session: " + session.getId(), t);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(FTPWebSocketRequest request, Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException, FTPWebSocketException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(ackResponse);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(CloseReason reason, Session session) throws FTPException {   
        new EndSessionOnMessageHandler().handleMessage(null, session); 
    }
}
```

Comment: focus your coverage on more business-relevant code, there is no real benefit on cover boilerplates.